Background image not rendering in custom 404 page
I'm trying to set up a custom 404 error page in my Django project. The page renders correctly, but the background image is not showing up. I've ensured that the file name is correct and that it's located in the static folder. However, the image still doesn't display. Here's my code:
Code:
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .error-page {
            background-image: url('{% static "404image10.jpeg" %}');
            /* Add other background styling properties as needed */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid error-page">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <h1 class="display-1 text-white">Error 404</h1>
                <p class="lead text-white">Page not found</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>

I attempted to change the background image file to another one and verified that the file name and location are correct. However, the background image still does not render. Since the issue persists even after changing the file, I suspect that there might be an issue with the code itself. Could someone please help me identify and fix the problem?

perhaps div height/width is 0?

What exact result does {% static "404image10.jpeg" %} actually produce? It should be either a fully absolute URL, or a root-relative one that starts with a /. If it is a different kind of relative URL (relative to a specific folder), then this is unlikely to work in all possible situations - because your error document can be shown for URLs with different amounts of folders in the path.
